# Should the comma be inside the quotes in: I read "The Ghost," a short story by Hann?

Tags: punctuation, commas, transatlantic-differences

A [website](https://www.mbarendezvous.com/punctuation/) says:

> In Edgar Allen Poe’s short story, “The Tell-Tale Heart,” Edgar Allen Poe describes a man with a guilty conscience.

It is strange to put a comma inside the double quotation marks like that.

Why isn't it:

> In Edgar Allen Poe’s short story, **“The Tell-Tale Heart”,** Edgar Allen Poe describes a man with a guilty conscience.

Is it correct to write:

> I read "The Ghost", a short story by Hann.

or

> I read "The Ghost," a short story by Hann.

Some people say that the former is British English and the latter is American English.

Comment: It is impossible to explain punctuation because it is a set of arbitrary conventions. Whether a comma is inserted before or after a closing quotation mark cannot be heard in the spoken language because quotation marks do not correspond to any feature of the spoken language. Punctuation in the U.S. is determined by style manuals. What you view as strange is the norm in the U.S.

Comment: We write punctuation, we don't say it.

Answer (score 3):

In academia schools will adhere to a specific writing manual. But generally speaking, there's no rule that forbids inserting the comma before or after inverted commas (speech marks), it's usually a personal preference.  For example, I prefer to use italics for titles of books, films and songs.

> I read *The Ghost*, a short story by Hann.

Adding a comma within the closing speech marks looks odd to *me* because I might think (momentarily) that the title contains that punctuation mark. I would avoid that style, but again, it's only my personal preference.

> 4. I read “The Ghost,” a short story by Hann.

In my view sentences 3 and 4 are both correct; however, an American English speaker will advocate placing the **comma inside the quotes** while a British English speaker, will only place a comma inside the quotes if they are quoting someone.

> 5. “I have read *The Ghost* by Hann several times,” she said.

Comment: Book titles and film names may be italicized but most style guide recommend putting song names and the titles of short stories in quotes.

Comment: Hmm, not sure that *most* style guides recommend adding quotes. I could be wrong though.